# UIPrintInteractionController canPrintUrl always false with error CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource: failed with error code -15

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am facing issue with UIPrintInteractionController canPrintUrl always returns false and error code 
: CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource: failed with error code -15.
: ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateWithURL CFURLCreateDataAndPropertiesFromResource failed with error code -15.

Printing description of url:
**/var/mobile/Applications/49C03664-6108-40D2-94A3-C545F0234ACE/Documents/mypdf.pdf**

its a valid PDF and open in adobe reader and UIWebView.

```
-(void)printButtonTapped:(CGRect)rect
{
    if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable] == YES)
    {
        // NSURL *fileURL = document.fileURL; // Document file URL
        NSString* str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/mypdf.pdf",NSHomeDirectory()];
        NSURL* url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];



        if ([UIPrintInteractionController canPrintURL:url] == YES)
        {
            self.printInteraction = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];

            UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
            printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
            printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
            printInfo.jobName = [url lastPathComponent];;

            self.printInteraction.printInfo = printInfo;
            self.printInteraction.printingItem = url;
            self.printInteraction.showsPageRange = YES;

            if ([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) // Large device printing
            {
                [self.printInteraction presentFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES completionHandler:
                 ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error)
                 {
#ifdef DEBUG
                     if ((completed == NO) && (error != nil)) NSLog(@"%s %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
#endif
                 }
                 ];
            }
            else // Handle printing on small device
            {
                [self.printInteraction presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:
                 ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error)
                 {
#ifdef DEBUG
                     if ((completed == NO) && (error != nil)) NSLog(@"%s %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
#endif
                 }
                 ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I load the above url in WevView then it display the PDF.
if I pass the pdf loaded webview.request.url to `[UIPrintInteractionController canPrintURL:webview.request.URL]`
Then working fine and print the pdf.

I don't know whats wrong going on I am running on ios7 and ios8.

can anyone please help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: I removed if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable] == YES) and in iOS 8 directory path changes on every run so confirm you are pointing valid existing file.

Answer (score 0):

Either the file is not found at the specified location or File name contains a whitespace. The webview expects encoded whitespaces in the file URL while UIPrintInteractionController expects normal whitespaces in the file URL. Fixing that should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the there is a difference between `canPrintData` and `canPrintURL`:

**Code**

```
NSString* str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/mypdf.pdf",NSHomeDirectory()];
NSURL* url=[NSURL URLWithString:str];
if ([UIPrintInteractionController canPrintURL:url] == YES)
....
```

is not right. For local files, you shall use:

```
NSString* str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/mypdf.pdf",NSHomeDirectory()];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str];
if ([UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:yourfilepath] == YES)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **UIPrintInteractionController.printableUTIs** to check if your file type (.pdf,.docx,.txt) is supportable for print or not .